# Using JQuery to sort an XML database file

Tags: jquery, xml, database, sorting

I need to sort the columns an XML based database file. Does anyone know an efficient way to approach this?

Here is an example of the XML, I'd be rewriting the XML file such that the columns are in the order CUSTOMER_NO, MNEMONIC, Z-FIELD and of course re-ordering all related data fields.

```
<table>
  <columns>
    <column name="Z-FIELD" columnType="2" indexType="0" timefixType="0" sortOrder="0" />
    <column name="CUSTOMER_NO" columnType="2" indexType="0" timefixType="0" sortOrder="1" />
    <column name="MNEMONIC" columnType="2" indexType="0" timefixType="0" sortOrder="2" />
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[103]]></element>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[101]]></element>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[102]]></element>
    </row>
    <row>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[203]]></element>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[201]]></element>
      <element isNull="false"><![CDATA[202]]></element>
    </row>
  </rows>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is an actual XML database (like Oracle's XML database, for example) then you'd be crazy to use jQuery instead of the built-in sorting capabilities. If you really are using a XML database, then you will see far better performance from learning your database's specific sorting commands for XML.

Comment: It's my homemade javascript based database engine.